# Why curl doesn't work in livenessProbe in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, curl

I have livenessProbe like this

```
livenessProbe:
    exec:
        command:
            - curl
            - --fail
            - -X POST
            - http://localhost/test
            - '-d "data"'
```

This probe doesn't pass and I see in `kubectl describe pods/pod_name` error

```
Liveness probe failed:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     7    0     0  100     7      0     62 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    63
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
```

But when I place the same curl query to file `/tmp/a.sh`

```
curl --fail -X POST http://localhost/test -d "data"
exit $?
```

and set liveness probe on this file

```
livenessProbe:
    exec:
        command:
            - sh
            - /tmp/a.sh
```

everythink works and no error about 400 from curl. When I go into container manually and run curl query, it's also ok.

Why the same command differently working in liveness probe, when it's placed in file?

Comment: Try to use `-d "data"` instead. Also the first approach on the following answer should work https://serverfault.com/questions/1086424/livenessprobe-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: Variant without signle quote `-d "data"` doesn't effect, but answer from that question really works, thanks.

Comment: You are passing `-X POST` as a single shell word, and I believe this will cause Curl to send an HTTP method ` POST` with a leading space.  Try splitting that into two options or removing the space in the health check.  (And try quoting `'-X POST'` in your script to see if you can reproduce the behavior.)

Comment: -XPOST works, looks like space is really cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Passing -X POST as a single shell word, will cause Curl to send an HTTP method  `POST` with a leading space.

Removing the space `-XPOST` works